# Sharing Mysql DB table between different user account

Tags: php, mysql

I am presently working on my school project with has to do with different client account but one database table. this is a database where users can store information via a web-form, but what I wish to know is how can I segment this contacts to only see their own data saved , since all data will be stored in one db table.

For example, I have a database called `clienti` and a table with columns height, hair colour etc ..

Now these are to be shared by two user accounts - User1 and User2.

User 1 should only be able to see only data that he has entered, and same applies to user two.

What is the best way I can achieve this?

I am new to php and mysql so your explanations &/or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add another column in table where can be stored user name (or their id) who inserted the data

Comment: This is sometimes called a *multi-tenant web application*. You can look that up with your favorite search engine.

Comment: hi Levin , thanks , i had already thought about this you know , but the thing here is having to create a seperate php access files for each user that triggers the appropriate table , imagine if we had like 100 people , then we have to makeout 100 .php files for each guys  with non changeable table id used for identification

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the comments:

The best way to do this is to have an additional column in the database that is the user ID that owns the record. This user ID is not modifiable by the user to prevent a user from accessing someone else's data.

When you query the database on behalf of a user, your query has a where statement with user_id equals the user ID of the user that is making the request.

The more complicated way to accomplish the same thing is to have separate databases or separate tables for each user. Most of the time this is a bad idea unless there is enough data that a performance gain can happen because of the separation.

Comment: thanks David , but overall what if i decide to have 1DB and multiple tables , each table for each user , so that the only thing to do is duplicate table data and then change the name.... , although it also comes to the face that the same proccess will be done for each user